# Tracking Viewing Habits of Website Visitors

Tags: javascript, http, web, tracking, visitor-pattern

First time using this service for a question. I hope I am not asking something that has already been answered. I attempted to find an answer to my question with the search engine but i was unable to.

My question is as follows:

Using php, javascript, or anything actually, is it possible for me to track how my users are viewing the pages on my blog/website? Specifically, I want to track the time the user's browser spends reading specific sections of my content on the same page.

For example, it would answer questions such as: How much time did someone spend reading the introduction to my article vs the conclusion? (located on the same page)

Basically, tracking the "eyes" of a web visitor by looking at where the browser is currently scrolled down the page too.

I'm sorry if i'm a bit noob! Thanks for any help with my problem you can provide to me! ^_^

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323375/how-to-measure-visiting-time-of-a-user

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-user-leaves-a-web-page

Comment: I don't think this is a dup; it's actually a pretty good question.  He wants to use scrolling as an indicator in statistics and I'm not sure how many analytic apps do that (although I have no experience and haven't checked).

Comment: Robert I appreciate your diligent attempts to prevent duplicate questions. However, i believe that the two links you have just posted don't exactly mirror my question.

Sam got it right.. I want to somehow see what location on the current page my visitors are looking at. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would technically be possible by looking at the scroll position (which you can get with javascript) over time, but I think you find the data is extremely unreliable and doesn't actually correspond very well with what people are *actually doing*.

For example, when I open a new tab, it'll usually sit there in the new tab for several minutes until I start actually reading it. Then I might get half-way down and go and grab a cup of coffee. Then I finally get all the way to the bottom and close the window. That doesn't mean I spent more time reading the top & middle than I did reading the bottom, but that's what you would infer simply looking at the scroll position.

You might be able to get better information by looking at *other events* as well as just reading scroll position. For example, if you only record the scroll position in the 30 seconds before and after you detect a `mousemove` event, then you can be pretty sure that they were actually "on" your page during that interval. But it's never going to be a perfect statistic.

Comment: Codeka, thank you very much for your answer! To accomplish my idea, I would like to implement an algorithm that reacts to multiple "signals" (mousemove / scroll position) that would determine better information as you said. ^_^

Do you know what kind of resource toll this might take on a server?

Comment: It depends how much you record, how you store it, where you store it, how many visitors you expect and so on. I would imagine you could design a system that performs reasonably well, but that's kind of hand-wavey without more information about the exact scenario :)